# GitHub support for multiple directories

Tags: github

ALL,

I am managing multiple projects. All of them located on the GitHub and I'm using GitHub for Windows GUI and GitHub Shell.

Recently one of the projects got updated with the really big file name and so in order to keep the GitHub happy I had to move it from the standard place: c:\documents and settings\\My Documents\GitHub to just c:.

This created a disaster as I currently have two places to manage.

Is it possible to keep GitHub GUI happy and stop making new repository on the C:\? In other words, can I configure GitHub to use 2 source directories?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag the root folder of a git repo (the one under c:\ in your case) from Windows Explorer onto the start screen in GitHub for Windows. Then it can see your repo and can manage it in your non-default location.

Answer (score 0):

Not for a single repository.

You could move the entire repo to the C: drive.
Or you could manage 2 repositories, one in My Documents and the other on the C: drive.